# using foreach of class inside another class

Tags: javascript, foreach, this

I use foreach for instances of class ( let say class1 ) inside prototype method of another class(class2), anyway it works well but when I try to use (this) to refer to some vales of class1 it doesn't work, any help?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am sorry, I don't ask the right question. My problem was with scopes, it was like this: class1.prototype.calculate = { numbers.foreach(function () {
  console.log(this); 
}); I assume "this" will refer to the instance of class1, but it didn't work. However I find the solution by making foreach take a second argument which refer to instance of class1, thank you gyus.

Answer (score 1):

*Step 1:* Look how to post questions on SO.

*Step 2:* If you program JS you need to know how this works, this case is not the real issue, the issue is you don't. Plenty of tutorials to google on that, I would recommend it since **understanding how `this` works in JS is essential**.

Depending on your actual code this could be enough to get you going:

The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

So in a place where you call your function try using this beforehand:

```
var _this = this;
```

Then call your function:

```
whateverobj.myfunction().bind(_this)
```